# Eclipse Ant Javadoc - warning of no comment on private field

Tags: eclipse, ant, javadoc

Running the Ant Javadoc process in Eclipse (2022-09 (4.25.0))  with  <javadoc access="public"

Getting a handful of these warnings on private fields.  However, there are many private fields that it does not complain about.

```
 [javadoc] D:\workspace_12\...\NetConfCredential.java:47: warning: no comment
 [javadoc]  private boolean verified = false;
```

It should be ignoring all private fields, no?  It does not complain about all of the private methods that do not have javadoc.

=====================
While minimizing the code to post an example, I found that it has to do with java.io.Serializable.

```
public abstract class TestAbstract implements java.io.Serializable
{
        /** Our serialization ID */
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 12;
}

/**
 * Comment.
 */
public class TestCredential extends TestAbstract
{
        /** UID */
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 12;

    private static final String defaultString = "public";

    private boolean verified = false;

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public TestCredential() {   }
}

 [javadoc] D:\workspace_12\...\TestCredential.java:13: warning: no comment
 [javadoc]  private boolean verified = false;
 [javadoc]  

            ^
```

Remove Serializable from the superclass and the warning goes away.  Javadoc does not warn about the private static field.

========================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="javadoc">
    <target name="javadoc">
        <javadoc access="public" author="false"  
            destdir="d:..." doctitle="NMS Core" classpath="..."
            noqualifier="all" nodeprecated="true" nodeprecatedlist="true" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" 
            Public="true"

            sourcefiles="
            com\logikos\core\credentials\TestCredential.java
            "
            
        source="12" splitindex="false" use="false" version="false"/>
    </target>
            
            
</project>

     [javadoc] Standard Doclet version 17.0.5+8
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing a private field for which you get the warning and a private field you do not get the warning. Please also tell which JDK is used here containing the Javadoc that generates these warnings. By the way, your Eclipse is six releases behind. Please upgrade (even though this is unrelated to your issue). Please note, `access="public"` hides in public abstract classes protected methods that are intended to be implemented.

Comment: I added a sample to the post.  It has to do with java.io.Serializable.  I am using JDK 21.

Comment: Please show the complete `<javadoc access="public" ...?` Ant task and tell the Java version of the JDK containing the Javadoc executable used.

Comment: Added to post.  
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION="21.0.2+13-LTS-58"
JAVA_VERSION="21.0.2"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2024-01-16"

Comment: Why is `Public="true"` required in addition to `access="public"`? Does removing `Public="true"` change something? The [`<javadoc ...>` Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) supports the `executable` attribute. Could you test it with a Javadoc of a Java 17 JDK (I can confirm that [in Javadoc of Java 21 `-locale` is ignored for messages](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8222793?focusedId=14616469&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14616469) and maybe there are more issues in that version)?

Comment: I have been playing with various parameters assuming that I am misinterpreting something.  Public="true" being there or not there does not change the warning.  Just ran it with javadoc.exe from JDK 17 and I get the same result.

Comment: Does [`serialwarn="no"`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) help? [What is when you use `@Serial` in your code, which would require Java 14 or higher](https://www.baeldung.com/java-14-serial-annotation) (`source="12"` - better use a Java 11, 17 or 21 for which you get long term support)?

Comment: Changed source to 17.  Added serialwarn="no" but result is the same.  I properly commented my private fields to stop the warnings.  Just a handful of them.  Hopefully whoever owns the javadoc code sees this.  I like putting my comments on the end of the line with the field definition when the comment is short.  Makes the code easier to visually scan.  It would be nice if javadoc allowed this.  Thanks to all for your help.